# Printing odd and even numbers with two threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I would like to refactor this code printing odd and even numbers with two threads considering agile practice:

```
public class EvenOddNumberPrinter {

    private static class NumberPrinter {

        // To check if even number is printed or not.
        private boolean isEvenPrinted = true;

        public void printOdd(int number) throws InterruptedException {
            // Get a lock on NumberPrinter
            synchronized (this) {
                // Wait until even is not printed.
                if (!isEvenPrinted)
                    wait();

                System.out.println(number);
                isEvenPrinted = false;

                // Notify the other waiting thread which is waiting on
                // NumberPrinter
                // Other thread will get out of waiting state
                notify();
            }
        }

        public void printEven(int number) throws InterruptedException {
            synchronized (this) {
                if (isEvenPrinted)
                    wait();

                System.out.println(number);
                isEvenPrinted = true;
                notify();
            }
        }
    }

    private static class OddNumberGenerator implements Runnable {

        private NumberPrinter q;
        private int max;

        public OddNumberGenerator(NumberPrinter q, int max) {
            this.q = q;
            this.max = max;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 1; i < max; i = i + 2) {
                try {
                    q.printOdd(i);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static class EvenNumberGenerator implements Runnable {

        private NumberPrinter printer;
        private int max;

        public EvenNumberGenerator(NumberPrinter printer, int max) {
            this.printer = printer;
            this.max = max;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 2; i <= max; i = i + 2) {
                try {
                    printer.printEven(i);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int maxNumber = 10;
        NumberPrinter printer = new NumberPrinter();
        new Thread(new EvenNumberGenerator(printer, maxNumber)).start();
        new Thread(new OddNumberGenerator(printer, maxNumber)).start();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Inconsistency

In `OddNumberGenerator` your printer is called `q`.  In `EvenNumberGenerator` it is called `printer`.  Why the difference?

The odd one prints to `max-1` but the even one prints to `max`.  They should both print to `max`, otherwise you are assuming that `max` must be even.

#### No check after wait

After your `wait()` call, you don't check to see if you are in the correct state before printing the next number.  If both threads called `printOdd()`, it would happily print two or more odd numbers in a row.  It's not a problem with your program because your two threads are well behaved, but it isn't a very good example of using synchronization.

#### Simplification

You don't need separate `printOdd()` and `printEven()` functions that do almost the same thing.  You could combine them into a single `printNumber()` function.

Similarly, you don't need two number generators.  If you just added a `start` variable to the number generator, you could create an odd generator with a `start` value of 1 and an even generator with a `start` value of 2.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I Will redactor it accordingly. I would like to know whether all oops concept is followed properly.